# Zend Framework: How Do I 'auto' generate a SQL query correctly

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, zend-db-select

I want to generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT `rc`.*, `c`.`name` FROM `RunConfigurations` AS `rc` INNER JOIN `Clients` AS `c` ON rc.client_id = c.id WHERE (rc.client_id = ?) ORDER BY `rc`.`config_name` ASC
```

However I am getting:

```
SELECT `rc`.*, `c`.* FROM `RunConfigurations` AS `rc` INNER JOIN `Clients` AS `c` ON rc.client_id = c.id WHERE (rc.client_id = ?) ORDER BY `rc`.`config_name` ASC
```

The difference is I want `c.name`, not `c.*`
Using the following ZF PHP code:

```
public function fetchConfigurations($clientId = null, $order = 'rc.config_name ASC')
    {
        $db = $this->getDb();
        $stmt = $db->select()
                ->from(array('rc' => 'RunConfigurations','c.name'))
                ->join(array('c' => 'Clients'),'rc.client_id = c.id')
                ->order($order);

        if(is_numeric($clientId))
        {
            $stmt->where('rc.client_id = ?')
                ->bind(array($clientId));
        }

        $results = $db->fetchAll($stmt);
        if(sizeof($results) > 0)
        {
            $configs = array();
            foreach($results as $row)
            {
                $configs[] = $this->createRunConfigurationFromRow($row);
            }
            return $configs;
        }
        else
        {
            die($stmt->__toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is aggravating and I feel like I am missing something at either:

```
->from(array('rc' => 'RunConfigurations','c.name'))
```

or

```
->join(array('c' => 'Clients'),'rc.client_id = c.id')
```

and the ZF examples are not shedding any light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close! `join()` actually has a 3rd parameter in which you can supply the column names just like the 2nd parameter from `from()`.

This would mean that `->join(array('c' => 'Clients'),'rc.client_id = c.id',array('name'))` should generate the SQL you are looking for.

-- Quote from the [Zend Framework manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join.example-no-columns):

> The third argument to join() is an array of column names, like that used in the from() method. It defaults to "*", supports correlation names, expressions, and Zend_Db_Expr in the same way as the array of column names in the from() method.